# Storing nested array (2D array)

Tags: solidity, arrays, erc-1155

So I am making an ERC1155 token (for the batch mint pretty much). It is only ever going to mint NFT's (as you will see now now).

I am trying to batch mint tokens and store an array for each one. So each `tokenID` needs to have an `uint8[]` array associated with it. I am storing it in `stateStorageForNumbers_` which is  a mapping: `mapping(uint256 => uint8[]) internal stateStorageForNumbers_;`.

But I have no idea how to pull the array out of the 2D array to store it.

```
function batchMint(
        address _to,
        uint8 _amount,
        uint8[][] calldata _numbers
    )
        public
        onlyOwner()
        returns(uint256[] memory tokenIDs)
    {
        // Setting up tokenIDs for mint
        uint256[] memory amounts;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < _amount; i++) {
            // Incrementing the tokenID tracker
            _tokenIDsCount.increment();
            // Adding the tokenID to array
            tokenIDs[i] = _tokenIDsCount.current();
            // Amount is always 1 as only minting NFTs
            amounts[i] = 1;

            // HERE
            stateStorageForNumbers_[tokenIDs[i]] = _numbers[i][];
        }

        // Minting the batch of tokens
        _mintBatch(
            _to,
            tokenIDs,
            amounts,
            msg.data
        );
...
```

For ease of talking about it I am going to name the arrays quick, so its `_numbers[j][k]`.

So as you can see I am passing in a 2D array `_numbers`, where the length of the `j` array will be the same as `_amount`. The inner array `k` is what I am actually trying to store.

Inside the `for` loop I am creating new `tokenID` numbers, creating an array (that gets returned) with all the ID's, then setting the amounts to all be 1 (as I want to mint exclusively NFTs).

You can see how I am trying to store `k` in `stateStorageForNumbers_` by the `// HERE`, But this gives me the compiler error:

```
contracts/LottoNFT.sol:97:42: TypeError: Index expression cannot be omitted.
            lottoNumbers_[tokenIDs[i]] = _lottoNumbers[i][];
                                         ^----------------^

contracts/LottoNFT.sol:97:42: TypeError: Type uint8 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint8[] storage ref.
            lottoNumbers_[tokenIDs[i]] = _lottoNumbers[i][];
                                         ^----------------^
```

Is this possible? Do I need to make them fixed-size arrays? I am not sure where to go from here.  Thanks in advance, a stressed-out Sol dev.

Comment: what happens if you try `stateStorageForNumbers_[tokenIDs[i]] = _numbers[i];`?

Answer (score 1):

The comment is right, removing the `[]` fixes it.

```
stateStorageForNumbers_[tokenIDs[i]] = _numbers[i];
```

^ This works.